# How to set the app icon on info.plist?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have three schemes and for each scheme I have a **xcconfig** file. I'd like to setup a variable to set the **AppIcon** for each environment. For example, in my **hom.xcconfig** I set:

```
ICON = AppIcon-Hom
```

and in the others xcconfig files I set:

```
ICON = AppIcon
```

In the **info.plist** I set in the key **Icon file** the variable **${ICON}** but it is not working.

How to configure the app icon without create another target?

Comment: Try `$(...)`, i.e. parentheses instead of squiggly braces.

Comment: Not work with parentheses!

Comment: Aren't *xcconfig* files set for configurations instead of schemes?

Comment: I up-voted this question before @AndreSlotta's comment. TO the OP - you need to change your title. I focused on your last sentence - *"...without creating another target"* - which is more broad than using `info.plist`. If all you want is that, then I mistakenly thought you were asking a good question.

Comment: First of all I am newbie in iOS Development so I'd like to apologize for the ill-formed question. After read this article (http://onebigfunction.com/ios/2017/03/14/flavor-ios/) , I discovered that we have in the buid settings the property [Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name], there I change the value for Hom environment and works fine for me.